# Verified token creators?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

we are looking into launching a token on the Solana chain but with our little experience we doubt our own process a little and due to the 'set in stone' principe of blockchain we went looking on the web and found several token creation website but we would love to know if there are trusted or even verified website that can help us with setting up the token? Anyone got experience with websites like smithii or oriontools and how trustworthy they are? Other suggestions are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

OrionTools seems to be the de facto standard (at least most common) for no-code token creation.  If you're going DEX, once you create it, you use Raydium to setup your liquidity pool.  [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNg1NtKga88) has a couple good beginner videos on it.  *Not an endorsement of his token(s)*.